# Extends spring to support customed configuration, then got error

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to extend Spring to support customized configuration. I do it according [a guide](http://www.cnblogs.com/jifeng/archive/2011/09/14/2176599.html)

I got the following error and I don't know how to fix it:

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://localhost:8080/cutesource/schema/people]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

[image]

Comment: have you added spring aop jar in your classpath?

Comment: Please share your pom if you are using maven or share your lib list, which jars you have in your classpath?

Comment: spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar is included

Comment: these jar are included

Comment: spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar
org.apache.commons.logging.jar
org.apache.log4j.jar
spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar